# Defer calling constructor of member object declared in header until source file

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to do declare a member object within the class declaration within my header file. I want to *defer* the calling of the member's constructor until the corresponding source file.
This is *ideally* what I'd like, just for illustration:

```
// foo.h
class Bar(string First, string Second);
class Foo : public Base {
 public:
  Foo(int a);
  Bar  b;  // I don't want to construct here!
  ...
```

```
// foo.cc
Foo::Foo(int a)
  : base(a)
  , b("first", "second")  // <-- construct here
{}
```

edit: The code above is calling the "default constructor" for Bar. I get:

```
error: could not convert ‘{arg}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Bar’
   Bar bar;
```

Changing the type of `b` to a pointer will ripple through too many things.

Changing it to a REFERENCE is probably tenable. In the code below, since no constructor is called in the header file, that's okay for my needs!

```
// foo.h
class Bar;
class Foo : public Base {
 public:
  Foo(int a);
  Bar&  b;  // now it's a non-constant reference, but unassigned
  ...
```

```
// foo.cc
Foo::Foo(int a)
  : base(a)
  , b{"first", "second"}  // <-- construct here
{}
```

However, this results in the `error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Bar' cannot bind to an initializer list temporary`.  That makes sense too.

I guess I'm asking how would you do this?  Is something like `std::reference_wrapper` going to be useful?

C++11 is a restriction.

Comment: What's wrong with your initial code? That's exactly how you do it. Only thing wrong is that you can not forward declare `class Bar`. The compiler needs to know the size and alignment. Add `#include "bar.h"`

Comment: I assume he doesn't want to include the definition of the other class, and rely on an incomplete type, which prevents the initial code. He just keeps talking about "deferring constructor calls", which is absolute nonsense, and it's polluting his question.

Comment: So, OP, is @Blindy correct or is there some other problem?

Comment: If that is their problem, and they must have `b` itself be usable as if it were not a pointer, you could always have a private `std::unique_ptr<Bar> _b;` (declared *above* `b`) that you then initialize with `Foo::Foo(int a) : base(a), _b{std::make_unique<Bar>("first", "second")}, b{_b} {}` I guess? Probably mangled something there.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, I added the error I face.  There's a lot of code underneath `Bar`, which I'm omitting here.

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte: It's very good to omit code, **If** you verify you still get the same error. We want the minimal example - no more, no less.

Comment: `class Bar(string First, string Second);` That makes no sense.

Comment: @Blindy, I can and do include the full definition. My goal is (for this case) to not have the compiler construct anything as it parses header files.  I want to *defer*/*contain* the actual construction of Bar to the step where I compile foo.cc.  All the other code that uses Foo, and includes foo.h does not.

Comment: It's still not clear whether you're working with an incomplete `Bar` or not. Because if you are working with a complete type properly written (yet more garbage in the question, `class Bar(string First, string Second);`), the first code does work fine.

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte: Compilers don't parse header files. That's what the preprocessor does. The preprocessor literally  pastes the content of a header into each source file that uses it - so the code in `foo.h` is compiled over and over.

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte The compiler never parses header files. The preprocessor includes the header files in it's output. The compiler then parses the whole translation unit and will construct objects where you create them, usually at runtime, regardless whether the constructor is in the header or cpp file. Where you define the constructor does not alter when construction happens.

Comment: @MSalters, indeed when I made the simple code you see above, I don't get the error.  In reality there are >10000 different kinds of Bar, grouped in different kinds of Foo.  Underneath Bar is a LOT of code.  I'm going to have to talk to someone that knows it...  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte: That's why it is so good to reduce it to the simplest example that still shows the bug. You'll have less than a dozen lines left, out of those 10.000. Ask us about those 12 lines. Start by removing 9000 kinds of Bar, then the next 900. It seems daunting, but the power of divide-and-conquer also works outside algorithm class,

Comment: Yes, I got some help and we tracked this to the default constructor of what is seen here as "Bar".  It's getting called through some trickery, even though it doesn't look like it is.  I tried to DELETE this question, but S.O. won't let me. Sorry to waste your time. ... I never did understand how I might declare a reference in the header file and assign it in the source.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of a member object is called from **all** constructors of the containing class. That includes compiler-generated constructors.

Hence, you need to make sure that the definitions of all these constructors are in `foo.cc`. Now you only show `Foo::Foo(int)`, but that's not the constructor which is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I believe that underneath Bar, there is some trickery that is causing the default constructor to be called as the header file is parsed.  That's not my code, and I haven't dug far enough.

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte: Note that the compiler will not automatically generate a default constructor `Foo( )` for you. You must ask the compiler for it: `Foo() = default;`. The reason is that your class already has a `Foo(int)` constructor.

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte as MSalters had metnioned in the comments to the question, *"the default constructor to be called as the header file is parsed"* makes no sence since compiler does not parse header files.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyKolesnik, I should have said "preprocessor"...

I am trying to optimize compilation of files that include my header file.

Answer (score 0):

> I can and do include the full definition

It's exceedingly difficult to get a straight response to you so I'll go with that quote specifically and assume you meant you have a fully defined `Bar` type before your `Foo` definition.

If that's the case, your first part of the code does work as intended (once you fix the weird syntax and semantic and every other kind of errors, of course). Specifically, [this works as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/x11ro651f):

```cpp
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    X(string a, string b) {}
};

struct Y {
    X x;
    Y() : x("a", "b") {}
};
```